# Was the 1959 Tibetan Uprising really an uprising?

Tags: tibet

Was [the "1959 Tibetan uprising"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1959_Tibetan_uprising), sometimes called "1959 Tibetan rebellion" really an uprising/rebellion?  Why is it called "uprising"?

"uprising" to me signifies something violent, but the events in Lhasa in 1959 started with artillery towards Tibetan protesters in an area that was controlled by the Tibetan government. There were very few attacks against PRC forces. It seems to me that it was for the most part resistance to China taking over full control of their county (Which they didn't have according to the 17 point agreement)?

It was connected to violent resistance in other parts of Tibet,  but these didn't start in 1959.

Perhaps for Tibetans, it was when they stood up to China taking over their country?  And this has then become "uprising" in English?  (They are referring to the start of it as the  ["Tibetan Uprising Day"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_Uprising_Day))

(I am writing about this in my own language, and I am not sure what I should call it)

Comment: Seems to [question the existing narrative without any justification](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/922/1401). And a reference to an uncited authority "sometimes called" - by whom? in what context?  What is the agenda/bias of those who use that term.  Is there a formal definition of "uprising" or "rebellion"?  Does the use of the term match the normative consensus?

Comment: Are you questioning the events or simply the use of the word 'uprising'?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: to OP's credit, the very first sentence of the wiki page he links to currently starts with "The 1959 Tibetan uprising or the 1959 Tibetan rebellion".

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Please explain how I "question the existing narrative"?

Comment: @Olav - The existing narrative is that events in Tibet in 1959 were an uprising. Why do you disagree with that narrative?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace "uprising" to me signifies something violent, but the events in Lhasa in 1959 started with artillery towards Tibetan protesters in an area that was controlled by the Tibetan government.  There were very few attacks against PRC forces.

Comment: [Don't reply in comments](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3915/1401).  The sentence you've just typed in comments is fundamental to the question. If the Chinese government quelled the riot with artillery, then the Chinese government will naturally term it an uprising; they don't use artillery on things that are not uprisings. ipso facto.

Comment: To an American the word "uprising" reminds me of Indian uprisings against the Federal government and American, which were usually terribly violent as in Minnesota in 1862.  It seems to me that if Tibetans are OK with describing it as an uprising that is equal to admitting that there were many massacres, atrocities, and crimes committed in it.  In my opinion an uprising is so evil that if any group is OK with having their conflict described as an uprising the USA should automatically fight them.

Comment: "uprising signifies to me..."  that is a subjective opinion, equivalent to the ["do you feel as I do"](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) anti-pattern.  If there is an objective definition of "uprising", or an analysis of _who_ used the word _in what context_ then you're practicing history.

Comment: I hear the term "violent uprising" or "armed uprising" in the news enough that it seems fairly certain there can be non-violent and/or unarmed ones. Two examples I could find with a quick search were [this link](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/iran-demonstrations-viole_n_215189) and [this book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9490003-media-power-and-politics-in-the-digital-age), both of which refer to the 2009 Iranian Election Protests as an "Uprising".

Comment: @MAGolding I think that is an understanding of the term "uprising" that very few other people share, to say the least.

Comment: @T.E.D. If there are protests in Hong Kong, and China comes in, it's not an uprising  (That's roughly the situation in Lhasa in 1959 AFAIK).  If the streets declared independence, it would be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although interested parties disagree in very fundamental questions, it seems that both of them agree in that it was an uprising. Tibetans in exile commemorate it in the [Tibetan Uprising Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_Uprising_Day), [the Dalai Lama refers to it as uprising](https://fas.org/sgp/congress/2004/s031004.html), and for the Chinese government it was a reactionary uprising of the Tibetan elite ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1959_Tibetan_uprising#Aftermath)).

World history in the last century is full of incidents where the opposing parties extensively argued about if those were uprisings, peaceful demonstrations, peace-keeping operations, banditry acts, or anything else, and even nowadays there is [an ongoing trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_of_Catalonia_independence_leaders) whose main point of contention is if a given event was an uprising or it wasn't. However, about the 1959 Tibetan uprising everybody involved says it was an uprising. Whether that uprising or its suppression were legitimated is another question without any agreed answer in the foreseeable future.

Comment: I guess the Tibetans have their own term.  Perhaps it is no better English translation?  The last part of your answer refers to events in other parts of Tibet.  I think here "resistance" could be a better word.  (So there is a perhaps narrative that Chia were legitimate rules)

Comment: @Olav - Tibetans are likely to have their own Tibetan term to use when speaking in Tibetan, but it seems that even the Dalai Lama himself uses "Uprising" when speaking in English: https://fas.org/sgp/congress/2004/s031004.html .